# Link moving to Id looks weird

Tags: html, css, flexbox, positioning

Im making a simple site to exercise and i have `nav`- elements that move to and Id on the page. When i press them, they move down to the Id as they should but they move past it and it looks really unprofessional.Can you guys help me so it actually stops at the headers? Idk if you guys understand what i mean ,try it out yourself : https://itsolidude.github.io/Tea_Cozy/

link to my repository : https://github.com/itsolidude/Tea_Cozy

plain code :

```css
html {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: seashell;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.9;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 69px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid seashell;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: black;
  top: 0;
}

#locations h2 {
  flex: 1 0 100%; /* shorthand for: flex-grow:1;
                                    flex-shrink: 0;
                                    flex-basis: 100%; */
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;   /* found this to be a simpler solution, and i sticked with it even tho i dont have exact 10px :p */
  top: 1510px;
  z-index: 3;
}

img {
 height: 50px;
 padding-left: 10px;
}

nav span {
  color: seashell;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.mission-banner {
  background-color: black;
}

.mission-banner h4 {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration-color: seashell;
}

#mission {
  background-image: url(../images/img-mission-background.jpg);
  position: relative;
  margin: 70px auto 0;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 700px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

#tea-of-month {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto 70px;
}

#tea-of-month img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
}

.contact {
  height: 200px;
}
#locations {
  height: 500px;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-image: url(../images/img-locations-background.jpg);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.address {
  background-color: black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  opacity: 1;
}

#copyright {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tea Cozy | Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <img src="./resources/images/img-tea-cozy-logo.png" alt="our logo">
      <nav>
        <a href="#mission"><span>Mission</span></a>
        <a href="#tea-of-month"><span>Featured Tea</span></a>
        <a href="#locations"><span>Locations</span></a>
      </nav>
        </header>
  <!-- main-content,our mission -->
        <div id="mission">
          <div class="mission-banner">
            <h2>Our Mission</h2>
            <h4>Handpicked, Artisanally Curated, Free Range, Sustainable, Small Batch, Fair Trade, Organic Tea</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
<!-- tea of the month -->
      <h2>Tea of the Month</h2>  <!--ERROR HERE, ITS HIDING BEHIND THE .MISSION DIV -->
      <h4>What's Steeping at The Tea Cozy?</h4>
      <div id="tea-of-month">
        <div class="item">
          <img src="./resources/images/img-berryblitz.jpg" alt="A picture of Fall Berry Blitz Tea">
          <span>Fall Berry Blitz Tea</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="./resources/images/img-spiced-rum.jpg" alt="A picture of Spiced Rum Tea">
          <span>Spiced Rum Tea</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="./resources/images/img-donut.jpg" alt="A picture of Seasonal Donuts">
          <span>Seasonal Donuts</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="./resources/images/img-myrtle-ave.jpg" alt="A picture of Myrtle Ave Tea">
          <span>Myrtle Ave Tea</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="./resources/images/img-bedford-bizarre.jpg" alt="A picture of Bedford Bizarre Tea">
          <span>Bedford Bizarre Tea</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- locations section -->
      <div id="locations">
        <h2>Locations</h2>
        <div class="address">
          <h3>Downtown</h3>
          <p>384 West 4th St</p>
          <p>Suite 108</p>
          <p>Portland, Maine</p>
        </div>
        <div class="address">
          <h3>East Bayside</h3>
          <p>3433 Phisherman's Avenue</p>
          <p>(Northwest Corner)</p>
          <p>Portland, Maine</p>
        </div>
        <div class="address">
          <h3>Oakdale</h3>
          <p>515 Crescent Avenue</p>
          <p>Second Floor</p>
          <p>Portland, Maine</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="contact">
        <h2>The Tea Cozy</h2>
        <h5>contact@theteacozy.com</h5>
        <h5>917-555-8904</h5>
      </div>
      <!-- copyright -->
      <h5 id="copyright">copyright The Tea Cozy 2017</h5>

  </body>
</html>
```

pls explain to me what u did and why :P?

Answer (score 0):

For a smoother experience, you can use javascript and the method [scrollIntoView](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_scrollintoview.asp). This method can take an object that you can specify where to align.

Comment: ty very much, but im searching for a solution with css. i believe my header is messing everything a bit up

Comment: Well, your solution puts the element at the top of the screen, and yeah your header is infront of it. You could try to squeeze a random element somewhere that takes into account your header and href to that element, however it won't look as nice as javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery library and then animate it.

[jsfiddle.net/zoz12kzu](http://jsfiddle.net/zoz12kzu)

```
$('a[href*=#]').click(function(event){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need only use CSS and smooth scroll

Use `translateY`

Example: [jsfiddle.net/3Lkk50rb](http://jsfiddle.net/3Lkk50rb)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and nothing was working until I found this: 
Basically you have to target the div where you want to scroll. Hope it helps!

```
//HTML
<a href=""> <li id="about" data-target="me">About me</li></a>    
<div id="me"></div>

//JQuery
$(document).on('click','#about', function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 var target = "#" + this.getAttribute('data-target');
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
 }, 500);
});
```